# NodeJS, Express, Sequelize - How to use bulkCreate for dynamically changing number of inserts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, ejs

Hi so I'm making an app using Node JS, Express JS, Sequelize and EJS Templating for a project. The app is designed to allow employees to leave Feedback for their team members. Right now I have functionality in the app to display the questions I want from the database to the view. I can also post single inserts such as - as a manager, sending a request for user1 to leave feedback for user2.

So, I can do GETs and POSTs (for single inserts) BUT my question is HOW am I meant to do a POST for this feedback form when the questions would vary depending on the role, etc?

e.g. developer could have 10 questions, product owner could have 8 and they would be different from each set.

```
module.exports.questions = function(req, res){
    var models = require('../app/models');
    var db = require('../app/models/index.js');
    var FeedbackQuestions = models.FeedbackQuestions;
    var express = require('express');

    models.FeedbackQuestions.findAll({
        where :  { role : req.user.role}
    }).then(function(questions){
        res.render('selfform.ejs', {
            page_title : 'Self-Assessment',
            questions : questions,
            user : req.user
        });
    });
};
```

so thats how I render the file, and pass data to it. This is how I use the data being passed in on the EJS view.

```
<tbody>
<% for (var i=0; i < questions.length; i++){ %>
<tr>
    <td><%=questions[i].question%></td>
    <td><%=questions[i].description%></td>
    <td> user selection rating  </td
</tr>
<% } %>
</tbody>
```

So, for example, I have 10 questions displayed (there could be more for an employee with different role).

```
module.exports.insertSelfFeedback = function (req, res) {
    var models = require('../app/models');
    var db = require('../app/models/index.js');
    var Feedback = models.Feedback;
    var express = require('express');
    var selfform = require('../views/selfform.ejs');
    var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));

    models.Feedback.bulkCreate([

        {
            fromuser: req.user.username,
            touser: req.user.username,
            rating: input.rating,
            questionnumber: input.questionnumber,
            period: input.period
        }

    ]).then(function () {
        res.redirect('/selfassessment');
        console.log(input);
        return models.Feedback.findAll();
    }).then(function (feedback) {

        console.log(feedback);
    })
};
```

I created the above function to use Sequelize's bulkCreate, but how do I do this with a dynamic range of inserts?
Thanks

Comment: you can create array of object and add it in bulkCreate.

Comment: you will be receiving all the data in req?

Comment: okay, but how am I meant to put the specific data from the html into the js file that has the bulkCreate function? I know that there is a app.post('/selfassessment', feedback.bulkCreate) which would call that function but since there could be 10 question, or 20, how do I actually put the values I want into an array then call them in the js bulkCreate file?

Comment: how are you posting the feedbacks? I am confused that you're having problem whether on client side or server side..

Comment: @Shaharyar I'm using this in the server.js file app.post('/selfassessment', feedback.insertSelfFeedback);

Comment: Ok I get it. How do you call this API from front-end? What data do you post to this API? I need to know the input, then I can help you to insert into database..

Comment: @Shaharyar in the selfform.ejs file I have a form like this                     <form method="post" action="/selfassessment"> and then the <input> tags have ids/names like "rating", "questionnumber" etc. and then on server.js the POST for that url is callling that insertSelfFeedback function.